# Nestjs Mongodb always return empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am trying to create a simple nestjs project that connects to mongodb. I followed the official [documentation of nestjs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb), but connected to my own db with "user" collection.
When I tried to call the endpoint to findAll user, the result is always empty, even though the db contains records.

Any idea on what is causing the issue?

```
// user.schema.ts
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type UserDocument = User & Document;

export class Credential {
  @Prop()
  username: string;

  @Prop()
  password: string;
}

export class NameDetails {
  @Prop()
  firstName: string;

  @Prop()
  lastName: string;
}

export class ContactDetails {
  @Prop()
  email: string;

  @Prop()
  phoneNumber: string;
}

@Schema()
export class User extends Document {
  @Prop()
  _id: string;

  @Prop()
  credential: Credential;

  @Prop()
  nameDetails: NameDetails;

  @Prop()
  contactDetails: ContactDetails;

}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

```
// users.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { UserSchema } from 'src/schemas/user.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }])],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService]
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

```
// users.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { User, UserDocument } from 'src/schemas/user.schema';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<UserDocument>) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    return await this.userModel.find().exec();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I was not providing the DB name in the app.module.ts I only passed the URI to the mongodb cluster (not sure about the naming, please correct me if I am wrong), and every time you run the server it created a 'test' db on the cluster (with empty collection thus empty array), you can see that in the MongoDB Compass. The nestJS docs does not provide the DB name either.

Answer (score 1):

in the entity.ts, when adding @Schema() annotation, pls add the collection name.

example:

```
@Schema({ collection: 'users' })
```

Answer (score 0):

If your schema class name is `User`, then the actual collection name should be `users`, rather than `user`. Mongoose will attach an 's' with the class name after lowering the characters.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

first of all you forget the Schema in your schema model :

```
@Schema()
export class Credential {}
```

secondly in your module you must put the same name of schema in your mongoose feature like this :

```
 @Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: Credential.name, schema: UserSchema }])],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService]
})
```

it must now work fine